# Link To Images in The Same Subdirectory

Tags: html, image, xhtml

I have my images folder inside the same subdirectory folder. .

For example:

Domain: http://www.hebronics4u.com / subdirectory: webTract (http://hebronics4u.com/webTract/index.html - the images folder is in the same subdirectory folder.

I have tried all the following ways to get my pics to show and they will not show.

Here is the code:

```
 <img src="../webTract/images/billyGraham.png">
 <img src="webTract/images/billyGraham.png">
 <img src="images/billyGraham.png">
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Your background image is set to "images/" and that one works right.  So as long as your image is in that folder, and is spelled exactly like that, it should work (your third method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use absolute path.  `<img src="/webTract/images/billyGraham.png">`

What are there the errors in console logs?

Comment: This is the error from the console log:  "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)"

Comment: What is the permissions on the images folder and files?

Comment: I do not know how to access that or change it.

Comment: change chmod xxx file_name

Comment: Check permissions ls -l

Comment: I have a Mac. Is it the same as on the PC?

Comment: If your files are located in the Mac(no server). File → Get Info you will see privilege and can change it

Answer (score 1):

If the images are in exactly the same sub-directory (for example)

http://hebronics4u.com/webTract/index.html is your working file and

http://hebronics4u.com/webTract/billyGraham.png is where your file is situated, simply use the name of the image.

E.g.

```html
<img src="billyGraham.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

`<img src="./images/billyGraham.png">`
Also fix your permission on the subfolders.

Comment: How do your fix the permissions?

Comment: Looks like you figured it out. :)